# Is there anyway to make this R code more efficient?

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I'm applying a fertility model and to execute I need to save matrices for each childbearing intensity, which I called `mati`, according to its order. In this case, i=(1, 2, 3,...n)
The data frame bellow is an example of how my data is displayed. My real dataframe have 525 rows and 10 columns (`"AGE"  "year" "mat1" "mat2" "mat3" "mat4" "mat5" "mat6" "mat7" "mat8"`).

```
year <- c(rep(1998:2001, 4))
Age <- c(rep(15:18, 4))
mat1 <- c(rep(0.01, 16))
mat2 <- c(rep(0.012, 16))
mat3 <- c(rep(0.015, 16))
mat <- data.frame(year, Age, mat1, mat2, mat3)

mat

   year Age mat1  mat2  mat3
1  1998  15 0.01 0.012 0.015
2  1999  16 0.01 0.012 0.015
3  2000  17 0.01 0.012 0.015
4  2001  18 0.01 0.012 0.015
5  1998  15 0.01 0.012 0.015
6  1999  16 0.01 0.012 0.015
7  2000  17 0.01 0.012 0.015
8  2001  18 0.01 0.012 0.015
9  1998  15 0.01 0.012 0.015
10 1999  16 0.01 0.012 0.015
11 2000  17 0.01 0.012 0.015
12 2001  18 0.01 0.012 0.015
13 1998  15 0.01 0.012 0.015
14 1999  16 0.01 0.012 0.015
15 2000  17 0.01 0.012 0.015
16 2001  18 0.01 0.012 0.015
```

To execute get my final numeric matrices I already executed the code below, but it takes a long time.

```
##mat1###

library(dlyr)
library(tidyr)

mat1 <- #selecting just intensities of order 1 and creating matrices
  select(mat, Age, year, mat1) %>% 
  spread(year, mat1) 

names(mat1)[c(2:6)] <- paste0("year ", names(mat1[2:6])) #alter colnames
mat1[ ,1] <- paste0("age ", mat1[,1]) #alter the row from column "age"

mat_oe1 <- data.matrix(mat1[2:6])
dimnames(mat_oe1) <- list(c(mat1[,1]),
                          c(names(mat1[2:6])))
#Saving as txt to read i the model
write.table(mat_oe2, file = "mat_oe1.txt", sep = "\t",
            row.names = T, col.names = T)

##mat2
mat2 <- #selecting just intensities of order 1 and creating matrices
  select(mat, Age, year, mat2) %>% 
  spread(year, mat2) 

names(mat2)[c(2:6)] <- paste0("year ", names(mat2[2:6])) #alter colnames
mat2[ ,1] <- paste0("age ", mat2[,1]) #alter the row from column "age"

mat_oe2 <- data.matrix(mat2[2:6])
dimnames(mat_oe2) <- list(c(mat1[,1]),
                          c(names(mat1[2:6])))
#Saving as txt to read i the model
write.table(mat_oe2, file = "mat_oe2.txt", sep = "\t",
            row.names = T, col.names = T)

##mat3
mat3 <- #selecting just intensities of order 1 and creating matrices
  select(mat, Age, year, mat3) %>% 
  spread(year, mat3) 

names(mat3)[c(2:6)] <- paste0("year ", names(mat3[2:6])) #alter colnames
mat3[ ,1] <- paste0("age ", mat3[,1]) #alter the row from column "age"

mat_oe3 <- data.matrix(mat3[2:6])
dimnames(mat_oe3) <- list(c(mat3[,1]),
                          c(names(mat3[2:6])))
#Saving as txt to read i the model
write.table(mat_oe3, file = "mat_oe3.txt", sep = "\t",
            row.names = T, col.names = T)
```

I'm using `spread` because I need data with the format below:

```
mat1 

     1998        1999       2000       2001
15   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
16   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
17   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
18   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
```

I also started to write a loop, but I'm stuck in the first line already.

```
mat_list <- list()
for(i in names(mat[,3:7])) {
  mat_list[[i]] <- data.frame(
                      spread(
                        select(mat, AGE, year, mat[[paste0("mat",i)]]), year, mat[[paste0("mat", i)]]))
```

After applying the code above I've achieved the results below:

```
view(mat1)
        year 1998  year 1999  year 2000  year 2001
age 15   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
age 16   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
age 17   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
age 18   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01


view(mat2)
        year 1998  year 1999    year 2000    year 2001
age 15   0.012        0.012       0.012       0.012
age 16   0.012        0.012       0.012       0.012
age 17   0.012        0.012       0.012       0.012
age 18   0.012        0.012       0.012       0.012


view(mat3)
        year 1998  year 1999    year 2000    year 2001
age 15   0.015        0.015       0.015       0.015
age 16   0.015        0.015       0.015       0.015
age 17   0.015        0.015       0.015       0.015
age 18   0.015        0.015       0.015       0.015
```

Comment: You could put `mat1`, `mat2`, `mat3` in a list.  ... but that is only my opinion.

Comment: I get an error when I copy and paste your code. Can you verify the ```mat1 <- #selectin just intensities...``` line?

Comment: @jogo I've tried to put in a list and apply a loop. But I couldn't.

Comment: @Cole there is a mistake in the ```spread``` function. I did earlier and know it isn't working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Cole's answer.

```
mat %>%
    gather("mat", "val", -year, -Age) %>%
    mutate(Age=paste("age",Age), year=paste("year",year)) %>%
    group_by(mat) %>%
    group_map(~spread(., year, val))
```

purrr::group_map applies a function to each group, and returns a list where each list element is the result of the function applied to each group.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Age    `year 1998` `year 1999` `year 2000` `year 2001`
  <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 age 15        0.01        0.01        0.01        0.01
2 age 16        0.01        0.01        0.01        0.01
3 age 17        0.01        0.01        0.01        0.01
4 age 18        0.01        0.01        0.01        0.01

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Age    `year 1998` `year 1999` `year 2000` `year 2001`
  <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 age 15       0.012       0.012       0.012       0.012
2 age 16       0.012       0.012       0.012       0.012
3 age 17       0.012       0.012       0.012       0.012
4 age 18       0.012       0.012       0.012       0.012

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Age    `year 1998` `year 1999` `year 2000` `year 2001`
  <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 age 15       0.015       0.015       0.015       0.015
2 age 16       0.015       0.015       0.015       0.015
3 age 17       0.015       0.015       0.015       0.015
4 age 18       0.015       0.015       0.015       0.015
```

This was using the data slightly modified by Cole.

```
year <- rep(1998:2001, each = 4) #each was the change.
Age <- rep(15:18, 4)
mat1 <- rep(0.01, 16)
mat2 <- rep(0.012, 16)
mat3 <- rep(0.015, 16)
mat <- data.frame(year, Age, mat1, mat2, mat3)
```

Comment: I've edited my answer. Also look into ```group_split()``` which is about twice as fast although admittedly, I didn't rename the columns to "year 1998".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to `gather` and then `spread` the data. This allows you to do everything in two steps.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mat %>%
  gather(key, value, -year, -Age)%>%
  spread(year, value)%>%
  group_split(key)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 6
    Age key   `1998` `1999` `2000` `2001`
  <int> <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1    15 mat1          0.01         0.01         0.01         0.01
2    16 mat1          0.01         0.01         0.01         0.01
3    17 mat1          0.01         0.01         0.01         0.01
4    18 mat1          0.01         0.01         0.01         0.01

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 6
    Age key   `1998` `1999` `2000` `2001`
  <int> <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1    15 mat2         0.012        0.012        0.012        0.012
2    16 mat2         0.012        0.012        0.012        0.012
3    17 mat2         0.012        0.012        0.012        0.012
4    18 mat2         0.012        0.012        0.012        0.012

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 6
    Age key   `1998` `1999` `2000` `2001`
  <int> <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1    15 mat3         0.015        0.015        0.015        0.015
2    16 mat3         0.015        0.015        0.015        0.015
3    17 mat3         0.015        0.015        0.015        0.015
4    18 mat3         0.015        0.015        0.015        0.015
```

Or you can do it in base:

```
mats <- reshape(data = data.frame(year = mat$year,Age = mat$Age,  stack(mat, select = c('mat1', 'mat2', 'mat3')))
        , idvar = c('Age', 'ind'), timevar = c('year'), direction = 'wide')

mat_list <- split(mats, mats$ind)

mat_list

$mat1
  Age  ind values.1998 values.1999 values.2000 values.2001
1  15 mat1        0.01        0.01        0.01        0.01
2  16 mat1        0.01        0.01        0.01        0.01
3  17 mat1        0.01        0.01        0.01        0.01
4  18 mat1        0.01        0.01        0.01        0.01

$mat2
   Age  ind values.1998 values.1999 values.2000 values.2001
17  15 mat2       0.012       0.012       0.012       0.012
18  16 mat2       0.012       0.012       0.012       0.012
19  17 mat2       0.012       0.012       0.012       0.012
20  18 mat2       0.012       0.012       0.012       0.012

$mat3
   Age  ind values.1998 values.1999 values.2000 values.2001
33  15 mat3       0.015       0.015       0.015       0.015
34  16 mat3       0.015       0.015       0.015       0.015
35  17 mat3       0.015       0.015       0.015       0.015
36  18 mat3       0.015       0.015       0.015       0.015
```

**data**
I changed your data slightly so that each ID combination was unique.

```
year <- rep(1998:2001, each = 4) #each was the change.
Age <- rep(15:18, 4)
mat1 <- rep(0.01, 16)
mat2 <- rep(0.012, 16)
mat3 <- rep(0.015, 16)
mat <- data.frame(year, Age, mat1, mat2, mat3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I really need a separate matrix for each one of the ```mat``` variables. Unfortunately, they must have the format that I posted at the end of my question

Comment: Just subset it. ```mat1 <- result[result$ind == 'mat1']``` or I'd say go with having them all together.

Comment: I also tried to melt and then use ```tapply```. But I could'n achieve my objetive

Comment: Ok, I added an edit. It's now a list of ```tibbles``` which is preferable to having 10 separate variables in the global environment. Still, my gut is saying that there is no need to split the variables.

Answer (score 0):

**First reshape to long**

```
#add unique id to your data
mat$id=1:nrow(mat)
#reshape to long by mat
long1 = reshape_toLong(data = mat,id = "id",j = "all123",value.var.prefix = "mat")
#delet id column
long2=long1[,-1]
```

**Second reshape to wide**

```
#reshape wide by year
wide=reshape_toWide(data = long2,id = "all123",j = "year",value.var.prefix = "mat")
```

**Last get data**

**mat1**

```
wide[wide$all123==1,]
   Age all123 mat1998 mat1999 mat2000 mat2001
1   15      1    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01
4   16      1    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01
8   17      1    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01
12  18      1    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01
```

**mat2**

```
wide[wide$all123==2,]
   Age all123 mat1998 mat1999 mat2000 mat2001
3   15      2   0.012   0.012   0.012   0.012
5   16      2   0.012   0.012   0.012   0.012
7   17      2   0.012   0.012   0.012   0.012
11  18      2   0.012   0.012   0.012   0.012
```

**mat3**

```
wide[wide$all123==3,]
   Age all123 mat1998 mat1999 mat2000 mat2001
2   15      3   0.015   0.015   0.015   0.015
6   16      3   0.015   0.015   0.015   0.015
9   17      3   0.015   0.015   0.015   0.015
10  18      3   0.015   0.015   0.015   0.015
```

before use `reshape_toLong` and `reshape_toWide` functions, you need to install `onetree` package from my github `yikeshu0611` using command below

```
devtools::install_github("yikeshu0611/onetree")
library(onetree)
```

**Attention**: The data you provided has problem, so I use data changed by Cole

```
year <- rep(1998:2001, each = 4) #each was the change.
Age <- rep(15:18, 4)
mat1 <- rep(0.01, 16)
mat2 <- rep(0.012, 16)
mat3 <- rep(0.015, 16)
mat <- data.frame(year, Age, mat1, mat2, mat3)
```